# Google Maps V2: Searching a place according to address; without latitude and longitude

Tags: android, google-maps

So i have searched a lot about showing a place in google maps, but all of tutorial show a technique which requires Latitude and Longitude, but can someone please tell me a trick where i can achieve this using just the address string ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how good you are at android programming but, there is a component named AutoCompleteTextView and if you set its adapter as bottom code, it will connect to google maps  places and search for address you typed into autocompletetextview..

```
public class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Test";
    private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

    private static final String API_KEY = "Your_Api_Key";


    private ArrayList<String> resultList;
    public static ArrayList<String> refList=null;
    public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }};
        return filter;
    }

    private ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
        ArrayList<String> resultList = null;
        refList=new ArrayList<String>();
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
            sb.append("&components=country:tr");
            sb.append("&language=tr");
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                refList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("reference"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }

        return resultList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) in Android. This API includes `reverse geocoding`. Means, you provide an address and you get an ArrayList of [Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html) objects as a response if a result was found. The `Address` contains all necessary data about that place.

You can use it like this:

```
if(GeoCoder.isPresent()) {

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(YOURADDRESS, 5);
        if (!addresses.isEmpty()) {
            Address address = list.get(0);
            // do something with your address
        } else {
            // No results for your location
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: the thing is i want to add a marker on my maps according to the location, but i dont wanna use latitude and longitude, i wanna use the string address instead, can u help me with that ??!

Comment: @VarunBarve This is not possible. To place a marker on a specific position you have to use lat lng.